# Pure javascript to trigger keypress event

Tags: javascript

i am trying to trigger keypress event using pure javascript from console but unable to do so.

below is my code

```
var abc = document.querySelector("#main > footer > div.block-compose > div.input-container > div > div.input");
```

**Code 1:**

```
function fire( elem, type ) {

  var evt = elem.createEvent("Events");

  evt.initEvent( type, true, true, window, 1);

  elem.dispatchEvent(evt);

}

document.addEventListener( "plop", function() {
   console.log( "Fired a synthetic click event" );
}, false );

fire( abc, "plop" );
```

**Code 2**

```
var event = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");

event.initKeyboardEvent("keypress", true, true, null, false, false, false, false, 115, 0);
```

Any suggestion??

**Jsfiddel link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/mishragaurav31/VLZGk/1105/

i just want javascript code that can alert "keypressed"

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: hey, if possible create jsfiddle or add your html code also

Comment: Have a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574431/testing-keydown-events-in-jasmine-with-specific-keycode/23700583#23700583

Comment: try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348175/how-can-i-check-that-a-key-has-been-pressed

Comment: @priya_singh added more details

Comment: JS PURE - Look a example: https://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/simulate-keydown-event-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

How about this (sending the key with an onkeydown call): [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/fowijitite/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Please don't simply link to external resources. It's fine to demo your answer, but always imagine how good your answer is if your stripped all non stack overflow links from your answer.